# Lyx error, I am typing 0 and I get a sign

Tags: lyx

[image]

I am typing 0, but I get [image] what could I do? Sometimes I get my 0 othertimes I dont get my zero?

Comment: Perhaps you have a keyboard language setup that has changed? Regardless, we'd need more context here. Consider putting yourself in the shoes of someone else reading your question. How can they replicate your setup in order to provide the easiest solution possible?

Comment: I have found out the error. It lang because I used \mathlabb to create |R and pressed 0 in this field created by Lyx, I had to use a spacebar to get out of there first, otherwise the 0 is interpreted as the 0, like if I would use the at \mathlabb, anyway thanks for the comment and sorry it was imprecise!

Comment: @Werner the OP may get lucky and someone recognises the msbm font layout:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

you have misplaced the `}` closing the `\mathbb` font.
It should just apply to R

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts}

\begin{document}

$\mathbb{R_{>0}}$

$\mathbb{R}_{>0}$

\end{document}
```